# Organising JSON data based on time stamp. Help would be great

Tags: javascript, json, timestamp

for the life of me I am having trouble figuring this out, some help or an example would be greatly appreciated!

How can I organize this JSON data based on the "created_time" attribute using java script?

```
{"data": {
var time = { "id1" : [   
                                { "firstName" : "John",  // First element
                                  "lastName"  : "Doe",
                                  "create_time"       : "11:10 PM yesterday" },

                                { "firstName" : "Mary",  // Second Element
                                  "lastName"  : "Smith",
                                  "create_time"       : "13 minutes ago" },

                                { "firstName" : "Mary",  // Second Element
                                  "lastName"  : "Smith",
                                  "create_time"       : "8:11 PM yesterday" },

                                { "firstName" : "Mary",  // Second Element
                                  "lastName"  : "Smith",
                                  "create_time"       : "10 hours ago" },

                                { "firstName" : "Mary",  // Second Element
                                  "lastName"  : "Smith",
                                  "create_time"       : "6:51 PM 2 days ago" },

                                { "firstName" : "Mary",  // Second Element
                                  "lastName"  : "Smith",
                                  "create_time"       : "11:40 AM Mar 25th" },

                                { "firstName" : "Mary",  // Second Element
                                  "lastName"  : "Smith",
                                  "create_time"       : "12:01 PM Mar 25th" }

                              ],                                

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript's Array.sort method.

```
sortByDate(function(a, b){
  var dateA=new Date(a.create_time), dateB=new Date(b.create_time)
  return dateA-dateB //sort by date ascending
})
```

Finally

```
firstLevel.data.time['id'].sort(sortByDate);
```